# Why does stability come from binding energy and not mass

Tags: nuclear-physics, mass-energy, stability, binding-energy

The mass of a nucleus is given by:
$$
Mc^2=n M_n c^2+zM_pc^2-B(z,n)
$$
And we were told that nuclei want to maximise the binding energy per nucleon.  However, I don't see why they don't want to minimise mass per nucleon, that seems more logical to me.

Comment: $E = mc^2$, maximize bounding energy $\equiv$ minimize mass ?

Comment: They are almost the same, but the small difference in the mass of the proton and neutron do change things slightly

Comment: ok, now I understand the problem; why all neutrons do not decay to proton?

Comment: I understand that, you have the asymmetry term.  My question is, why is stability at the maxima of $B$ not at a minima of $Mc^2$ (I doubt they always coincide)